# how to enable the laptop keyboard instead of having the onscreen keyboard

Tags: windows-10

I am using a lenova laptop with Windows 10.  I have hit a key a few times now in error - don't know what key I hit but the laptop keyboard stops working and I can only use the onscreen one.  Is there a way to disable the onscreen keyboard so only the laptop keyboard is working?   Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Settings > Ease of Access > Keyboard** or just press the windows key and begin typing "keyboard" and press enter when you see a shortcut for on-screen appear in the search results.

The first switch at the top will toggle the on-screen keyboard.

[image]

Also, Windows often puts a button in the far right corner of the taskbar near the clock that toggles the on-screen keyboard. Its possible that you clicked this button by mistake. To remove it, right click anywhere on the task bar and uncheck the option for "Show touch keyboard button."

[image]